# XmlUtil.serialize : Outputs tags in uppercase

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper, cyberneko

I am trying to create a valid html document from html

```
    String content = getContent()
    def parser = new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()
    parser.setFeature('http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces', false)
    def slurper = new XmlSlurper(parser)
    def html = slurper.parseText(content)
    String xml = XmlUtil.serialize(html, )
    println xml
```

However, the output will have all the tag names in uppercase eg. HTML/BODY
How do I stop it from capitalizing the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but isn't it [here](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/settings.html) what You are looking for? Search for 'lower'. As far as I see You can just set it. But [here](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/faq.html) is the motivation why elements are always uppercase, HTML DOM specification plays role here. It means that probably all of us code invalid HTML :D